# Handling firebase real time changes in progressive web app

Tags: javascript, firebase, local-storage

I'm fetching the top news from hacker news API which is using firebase. I'm planning to build a progressive web app hence, I'm planning to cache the results into the localstorage.

The current code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/96voj1xh/), which fetch and render the top stories. The code is here:

```
var ref = new Firebase("http://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/");
var itemRef = ref.child('item');

var topStories = [];

var storyCallback = function(snapshot) {
    var story = snapshot.val();
    var html = '';

    if(story.score) {
        html = '<i>'+story.score+'</i> <a href="'+story.url+'" id="article_a">'+story.title+'</a>'      
    }

    document.getElementById(topStories.indexOf(story.id)).innerHTML = html;    
}

ref.child('topstories').once('value', function(snapshot) {
    topStories = snapshot.val();

    for(var i = 0; i < topStories.length; i++) {
        var element = document.createElement("P");          
        element.id = i;
        document.getElementById('items').appendChild(element);

        itemRef.child(topStories[i]).on('value', storyCallback);
    }
});

ref.child('topstories').on('child_changed', function(snapshot, prevChildName) {
    var ref = snapshot.ref()
    var index = ref.name();

    var oldItemId = topStories[index];
    itemRef.child(oldItemId).off();

    var newItemId = snapshot.val(); 

    topStories[index] = newItemId
    itemRef.child(newItemId).on('value', storyCallback);
});
```

If I add each stories into the localstorage (by tweaking the above code), how can I skip fetching it from firebase the next time (if it already presents and doesn't changed)?

Note that doesn't change part is important because I can easily get from local storage using the key, how ever it should be in sync with firebase as well. So wondering whether firebase has some way to handle this

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not missing any point you can simply check whether they already exists in local storage or not

```
if(localStorage.getItem('key')){
 //display here
 }else{

//fetch 
//save for next time
localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify('yourdata'));
 //and display here
}
```

Also you can generalize your function for fetching, display or rendering so you can call at multiple place.